# SSRS footer text color not changing

Tags: excel, reporting-services

We are applying a stylesheet to SSRS report footer. Footer Font color is set dynamically based on the configuration in the database.

When report is exported into Excel, footer color is always black. It is always black in the SSRS report as well. However PDF export shows the footer color correctly.

Has anyone faced this issue with footer color in Excel export? Is it not possible to change the footer color in Excel export? Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're just using a color that Excel doesn't typically use. Try matching your CSS to one of the 56 colors that Excel can accepts from SSRS. See:
[exporting-to-microsoft-excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

> "If more than 56 colors are used in the report, the rendering
>   extension matches the required color to one of the 56 colors already
>   available in the custom palette."

Comment: I did try all the basic colors which are supported by Excel.For exa. Blue #0000ff , Red #ff0000. None of the colors are applied to the footer text in excel export.

Comment: Actually, re-reading that after a long weekend, I think I'm interpreting it wrong. It sounds like if you are using many different colors in your report, more than 56, any colors beyond that will be shoehorned into one of the previous 56 colors. It's like Excel can't remember that many colors. That's a lot of color, unless you have a bunch of charts or something?

Answer (score 0):

I just struck a similar issue, but when Exporting to Word docx format. It seems to ignore the font settings for placeholders in a footer.

I was able to work around it using the technique described in the link below - you set the text as a Placeholder with Markup Type = HTML, then wrap the text in HTML tags as the Value e.g.

```
="<font color='blue'>My blue footer text</font>"
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18748.ssrs-multi-font-color-multi-font-size-within-a-single-field-textbox.aspx